# Possible to move Origen test_ids gem JSON files to sub-dirs within a Git repo?

Tags: origen-sdk

I use the [test_ids gem](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids) to keep track of my binning.  I noticed it stores the JSON binning files at the top level of the Git repository.  Is it possible to place them in a sub-directory?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, users caring about the internal storage file layout was not something that had been thought about until now.